# How to get info about which sobject a report refers to?

Tags: rest-api, reports-api

I have a few reports based on subjects (e.g. Opportunity, Lead, Account) and need to get info about these subjects. I tried to use url:

`GET "/services/data/<version>/analytics/reports/<report_id>/describe"`

for every report, but I didn't find any information about relations between report and sobject.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the response payload find "reportTypeMetadata > objectRelationships". There all related objects will be listed.

You can easily check it out in Workbench:

[image]