# Get report type objects and their relationship

Tags: apex

I'm trying to extract the metadata for different report types programmatically using apex. Currently, I am stuck on how to to retrieve the objects being used by each report type and their relationship to one another. Please refer to the image below to better understand what I'm talking about.

[image]

Here, you can see the two objects that are used, assets and activities, and their relationship. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_reporttype.htm#ObjectRelationship

Comment: I did see that before but how would i get that programmatically? That's the part I'm confused about

Comment: You would use [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_intro.htm) - lots of Q&As here on calling Metadata API, please do a search.

Comment: I am using the metadata api, and i have looked through the api as well as searching on this forum here. I still haven't been able to find how to do it. I've gone as far as `Reports.ReportTypeMetadata reportTypeMetadata = reportDescription.getReportTypeMetadata();` to get the report type metadata, but none of its methods have what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284498/how-to-get-info-about-which-sobject-a-report-refers-to

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I didn't look hard enough.